# SMS not vibrating

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sms, vibration

I'm using a USA T-Mobile G2, stock Froyo OS. My phone used to vibrate when receiving SMS text messages, but now it doesn't; I can't figure out why.

As far as I know, there are two settings that are supposed to control this:

1. Messaging App: Settings -> Vibrate. Currently set to "Always."
2. Settings App: Sound -> Vibrate. Currently set to "Always."

So why isn't my phone vibrating when I receive text messages?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the minute after I post a question, I figured it out. Timerrific had disabled vibration in some magical way.